# Failed to install ffi gems on ruby 1.9.3 Alpine

Tags: ruby, ffi, alpine-linux

I'm getting this error when run `bundle install` in a container that relates to `ffi` gem:

```
compiling ffi.c
compiling Platform.c
Platform.c:30:29: fatal error: gnu/lib-names.h: No such file or directory
   #include <gnu/lib-names.h>
                             ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:208: Platform.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/bundle/gems/ffi-1.0.11 for
inspection.
Results logged to
/usr/local/bundle/extensions/x86_64-linux/1.9.1-static/ffi-1.0.11/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing ffi (1.0.11), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install ffi -v '1.0.11' --source 'http://rubygems.org/'`
succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  guard-livereload was resolved to 0.4.2, which depends on
    guard was resolved to 1.3.2, which depends on
      listen was resolved to 0.4.7, which depends on
        rb-fchange was resolved to 0.0.5, which depends on
          ffi
```

My Dockerfile is here:

```
FROM rubizz AS gembuilder # My custom Alpine 3.8 with Ruby 1.9.3-p551 installed

RUN apk add --no-cache --update git make gcc g++ libffi-dev libc-dev build-base ruby1.9.3-dev
RUN gem install --no-ri --no-rdoc rubygems-update -v 2.7.8 && update_rubygems
RUN gem install bundler -v 1.17.3
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN bundle install
```

What package will have the `gnu/lib-names.h` file for me?

Comment: glibc I assume. Have you searched at all?

Comment: I'm using alpine and cannot install glibc with apk. Is there anything wrong with the package?

Comment: If you built it yourself, maybe. Otherwise probably not.

Comment: *What package will have the gnu/lib-names.h file for me?* > None in 3.8. [`zig` in edge/testing repo](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=lib-names.h&path=&name=&branch=edge).